# Use NotNullWhenAttribute when `#nullable disable`

Tags: c#

How can we use [`NotNullWhen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) attribute (or some alternative?) when `#nullable disable`?

For example I have an extension method:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>([NotNullWhen(false)] this IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    return e == null || !e.Any();
}
```

And usage

```
if(ids.IsNullOrEmpty()
{
    throw new Exception();
}

var id = ids.First();
```

The compiler shows me warning on `ids.First()`:

> Possible 'System.NullRefernceException'

If I do `#nullable enable` the warning disappears. I want to achieve same effect with `#nullable disable`. Is it possible?

**Update**
Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you show exactly where you have added those `#nullable` preprocessor directives?

Comment: Could you please share full warning text (especially warning code)? It's possible that it's generated with third party analyzer

Comment: This may not answer the question directly but you could use the `bang` operator. `var id = ids!.First();`

Comment: @Sweeper above the namespace. Of course enabling nullable references requires adding `?` in few places to make it work properly

Comment: @МаксимКошевой I have disabled R# but this warn still there, so I believe it's native Roslyn warn

Comment: @WBuck bang operator available only when `#nullable enable`, I need `disable`

Comment: @Artur Still, could you please share warning code? Judging be the text (seen in screenshot) it's a resharper warning (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AssignNullToNotNullAttribute.html), but one cannot be sure without a code. Strange that it doesn't have a code in the screenshot.

Comment: @МаксимКошевой I couldn't find the error code so I checked again resharper settings. I disabled it in one instance of VS and verified the effect in another (facepalm). After correct disabling the warning disappeared, it was R#'s static analysis. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@МаксимКошевой's comment pointed me to the correct direction: it's was Resharper's warning, not Roslyn. To hide this warning I installed `JetBrains.Annotations` nuget packages and used `[ContractAnnotation]` attribute like this:

```
[ContractAnnotation("null => true")]
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    return e == null || !e.Any();
}
```